# Redirect Logs to a specific file based on class name JBoss AS 7.0.0

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

I want to separate logs based on particular class name like if the class name is

```
    package com.task;

    public class MyService {
    /**
     * Logger.
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyService.class);
```

Then all the logs should be redirected to a file registered against this class name in JBoss `standalone.xml` file , for instance i have done like

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>

        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="MY_LOG" autoflush="true">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="my_log.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>


        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="com.task.MyService">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="MY_LOG"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>                    
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
```

The log file with name **my_log.log** is getting created but the logs are not redirected to that file they are still written over the **server.log** file by default.

How can i log the statements from this **MyService.class** to write into **my_log.log**  file only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shifted to higher version of Jboss ie. 7.1.1 for solving this issue , but after a lot of headache while looking for solving another issue i found a working **solution** [Here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/211986)  for Same **7.0.0 Version** 
Quoting from the Thread's answer

> you need to explicitly tell the JBoss container that your web
>   application needs log4j. And you do this by adding the following line
>   into /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>
> Dependencies: org.apache.log4j

Dependencies: org.apache.log4j

Thanks to the original contributor on that Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Anand ,

Few things to check:

1. Are you logging in debug level in MyService class. According to the configuration it will log only the debug statements.
2. Try introducing a log4j.xml with same configuration.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Yes Arun i am using debug statement only while logging , how introducing a log4j.xml will help , please elaborate, also externalize configuration is not supported see [https://developer.jboss.org/thread/176231?tstart=0 ] (see this)